# iOS - Swift and Parse error regarding Optionals within Subclass

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, subclass, option-type

I have implemented a Parse subclass called `Filler.swift`that contains five variables that are held in the Parse backend.

Whilst trying to save data to the Parse backend using this subclass I get the error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

This is the code that brings about the error (on the self.object.username = username line):

```
if let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {

        // set username equal to current user
        self.object.username = username

    }else{

        println("PFUser.currentUser()?.username contained a nil value.")

    }
```

I've figured out that it's something to do with how I'm handling optional variables in my subclass but the Parse documentation isn't clear on exactly how to do this. Here's my code for the subclass:

```
class Fillup : PFObject, PFSubclassing {

var amount : String? {

    get {

        return self["amount"] as? String

    }

    set{

        self["amount"] = newValue

    }

}

var cost : String? {

    get {

        return self["cost"] as? String

    }

    set{

        self["cost"] = newValue

    }

}


var date : NSDate {

    get {

        return self["date"] as! NSDate

    }

    set{

        self["date"] = newValue

    }

}

var username: String? {

    get{

        return self["username"] as? String

    }

    set {


        self["username"] = newValue

    }
}


var id : Int?{

    get {

        return self["id"] as? Int

    }

}

override class func initialize() {

    var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {

        self.registerSubclass()

    }

}

class func parseClassName() -> String {

    return "Fillup"
}
```

}

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: i wrote a python script to automatically generate these subclasses for you (https://github.com/Grepstar/GSParseSchema).  You'll want to define your properties as optionals, as you've done above, because you cannot guarantee non-nil values for any property.  In your case, it appears you are attempting to access the currentUser which is likely nil due to no user being logged in.  Your subclassing looks fine.

Comment: Parse SDK can generate the code for accessing these properties automatically behind the scene. 
Check: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a ? like so: 
`self.object?.username = username`

Comment: Thanks that got rid of the error :) now to find out why it's not saving to the Parse backend but I think that's another question for another day lol

Comment: Wait nevermind, now whatever I apply to the object is nil? Even when giving it the hard coded value "7" it still gets stored as a nil variable.

Comment: That is what I thought. I think there is a slightly bigger issue. But I'll need to read the doc on Parse

Comment: The documentation is barebones at best unfortunately. Doing `if let test = self.object?.amount {
        
            println(test)
        
        }else{
        
            println("Variable contains nil value")
            
        }` always returns the `else` statement and I can't seem to get it to do otherwise.

Comment: You'll have to post your code where you are initializing `self.object`

Comment: I'm initialising it at the top of the view controller like so `var object : Fillup?`

Comment: I was able to find the following doc. The documentation (i.e. user guide/ tutorial) is clear and rich: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users/iOS

Comment: The code `var object: Fillup?` initialises `object` to nil. It makes sense that everything you try to 'save' in the object would show as `nil`, because `object` itself is nil. You need to actually initialise your object, by calling, e.g. `self.object = Fillup()` (or whatever the designated initialiser is). This is basically what I was getting at in my comment on your other question.